# Jenkins: Use personal credentials for project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I'm hosting a project on my Jenkins server. That project has a GitHub repo and I have it set up so it automatically builds new commits. In order for that to work, I need to input credentials for a github account that has full access to the repo.

The problem is, that if I want him to add his login info to the credentials list, I'd have to give him acces to all credentials on the server (I don't want that).

I tried using the credentials under **"{username}" > "Credentials"**, but those didn't show up in the project setup (even with 100% access to everything on the server).

Is there a way for the user to store his credentials and use them for the project without giving him full access to all credentials on the server?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. You can restrict access to projects by login

Comment: I do not understand the question. Could you clarify the following: when you say "server", do you mean Jenkins server or Github server? When you say "account", do you mean Jenkins account or Github account?

Comment: Server is the Jenkins CI server and the only time I mentioned "account" was a GitHub account.

Comment: When you set up credentials, you need credentials binding plugin to use them in your project. Although they will still show up in job building logs.. That's what I'm currently fighting with, to see how I can make Jenkins stop logging those ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the user's credentials under Global security and then allow project based Matrix Authorization Strategy per project as shown:

[image]

Comment: I don't mean credentials as in Jenkins users. I mean external credentials (GitHub...) using the Crenedtials plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this [mailing list entry:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/t9z2uLuvf74)

**In short:** You need to

1. install and activate the [Authorize Projects Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin),
2. enable "run as specific user" strategy in global security settings,
3. enable this for the project in question.

This allows you to use the credentials for this specific user.

Enabling **ssh-agent** is the final step to make this work conveniently.